# Design Django MongoDB Engine foreign key list

Tags: python, database-design, mongodb, django-nonrel, non-relational-database

When we use Django MongoDB Engine to implement ManyToManyField, 
we can design it like below:

```
# Model and its field
class Group(models.Model):
    members = ListField(models.ForeignKey(User))

# Query
Group.objects.raw_query({'members': ObjectId(request.user.id)})
```

The one above will store the field "members" as Mongodb ID list in mongodb. Like `"members" : [ ObjectId("4e46434741b6994c70000000") ]`

We can also store MongoDB id as string:

```
# Model and its field
class Group(models.Model):
    members = ListField(models.CharField(max_length=24))

# Query
Group.objects.filter(members=request.user.id)
```

The one above will store the field "members" as string list in mongodb. Like
`"members" : [ "4e46434741b6994c70000000" ]`

My question is, which one of these structures is more efficient for mongodb query?

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key defiantly. The model you're pointing to will use an objectid as it's _id, so by storing the relation as a string you need to convert from a string to an objectId for each item in the list.